# Websockets with NextJS in Heroku

Tags: heroku, websocket, next.js

Is it possible to use websockets with NextJS in Heroku?

I have a web app deployed in Vercel. Vercel does not support websockets. They recommend to use a third-party service. The problem is that this service doesn't work properly. I've implemented it already without getting the desired result. Doing some research I found out that the nature of Vercel makes it difficult to implement websockets.

Some people recommend to use Heroku. Heroku supports websockets. But it's not clear to me if I deploy my NextJS project on Heroku I'll be able to implement websockets out of the box. Or do I have to port my project to a different technology like ExpressJS.

Comment: Did you figure it out by the way? I have same problem..

Comment: @SahilRajput Unfortunately, I couldn't make it work on Vercel. I had to use a different hosting that supports websockets or third-party service. Also, it is a good practice to have the websockets server as an independent service.